# How to display Array of values in tableview view for header in section?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I have one array for displaying values in table view section header. So, for displaying this array of values in section i used `– tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:`. Initially its displayed all values in array correctly but when I scrolling tableview this section values are changed instead of original values. please guide me what happening there.

i wrote like this in tableview Viewfor header in section

```
UIView *headerView=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 323, 50)];

//Background Image
///UIImageView *headerBg=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"arrow-button_50.png"]];
/// [headerView addSubview:headerBg];

//Button
UIButton *button=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
button.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 215, 70);
button.tag=section+1;
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"down_arrow.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"right_arrow.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];



if([[self.cellcountarray objectAtIndex:section] intValue]==0) 
    button.selected=YES;
else button.selected=NO;

[headerView addSubview:button];
NearbyPeople *obj=[self.sectionArray objectAtIndex:section];
NSLog(@"first name from section %@",[self.sectionArray objectAtIndex:0]);
UILabel *headerTitle=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(30, 15, 300, 30)];
[headerTitle setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[headerTitle setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:15]];
[headerTitle setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
headerTitle.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"      %@",obj.FirstName];

NSLog(@"header text is %@",headerTitle.text);
///[headerTitle setText:obj.FirstName];
[headerView addSubview:headerTitle];
[headerTitle release];
```

Thanking in advance

Comment: Can you be more specific? What type of view is it? What sort of value s? How do they change? What does your code look like?

Comment: What is the contents of sectionArray, also can you show your numberOfSectionsInTableView method? Or really just show the entire class?

Comment: please post your console output (nslog output) and what you think it should say

Comment: Actually i don't have any errors at that time but only values are changed when scrolling table view.Total section array values are changed.

Answer (score 0):

It is not the problem of your data.So after end of your scrolling just `[self.tableview reloadData]`

```
   - (void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate {

[self.tableView reloadData];

}
```

May be it will work now.